# MySql Preferential Sorting Using FIELD

Tags: mysql

### Student table :

```
----------------------
id  | name 
______________________
1   | Name 1
2   | Name 2
```

### Course Table :

```
id | student_id | ctype    | level
__________________________________
1  | 2          | beginner | complete
2  | 2          | advanced | current
3  | 1          | beginner | current 
4  | 2          | intermed | skipped
```

From the above two table i am trying to get the latest user records based on the level from course table . the level should be matched such that it checks for  current, complete and skipped in the same order so if the user has a level of current for any course type it should be fetched else check the level complete...

i am using the following query .

```
SELECT `sc`.`student_id`, 
        `s`.`name`,  
        `sc`.`id` as `course_id`, 
        `sc`.`ctype`, 
        `sc`.`level`,
FROM `course` `sc`
LEFT JOIN `students` `s` ON `s`.`id` = `sc`.`student_id`
WHERE sc.id = (SELECT ssc.id FROM course ssc WHERE ssc.student_id = sc.student_id  
ORDER BY FIELD(`ssc`.`level`,"current","complete","skipped") DESC LIMIT 1,1)
GROUP BY `sc`.`student_id`
ORDER BY `sc`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

The problem with the above query is it displays only if there is more than one user id matching in course table . so the final output i get is it displays only the student with id 2 and ignore the student with id 1 as there is no more than one .

### Result form above query

```
   student_id | name   |  course_id | ctype    | level |
=====================================================
     2        | Name 2 |  2         | advanced | current
```

### Expected Result

```
   student_id | name   |  course_id | ctype    | level |
=====================================================
     2        | Name 2 |  2         | advanced | current
     1        | Name 1 |  3         | beginner | current
```

**NOTE : I have also tried FIELD_IN_SET and IN instead of FIELD im getting the same result**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `LIMIT 1,1` to `LIMIT 0,1` or just `LIMIT 1`.

Unlike most other things in SQL, the `offset` field in the `LIMIT` clause is 0-based, not 1-based. So if there's only 1 matching row, `LIMIT 1,1` skips over it. And if there are 2 or more matching rows, you're not getting the top match, you're getting the 2nd match.

Also, the ordering should be `ASC`, not `DESC`, since you want to prefer the lowest field (`current`), not the highest.

```
SELECT `sc`.`student_id`, 
        `s`.`name`,  
        `sc`.`id` as `course_id`, 
        `sc`.`ctype`, 
        `sc`.`level`
FROM `course` `sc`
LEFT JOIN `students` `s` ON `s`.`id` = `sc`.`student_id`
WHERE sc.id = (
    SELECT ssc.id FROM course ssc 
    WHERE ssc.student_id = sc.student_id  
    ORDER BY FIELD(`ssc`.`level`,"current","complete","skipped") ASC 
    LIMIT 0,1)
GROUP BY `sc`.`student_id`
ORDER BY `sc`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94ff7/4)

There's also no need for `GROUP BY`sc`.`student_id`. The query is only returning one course ID per student, so there can't be multiple rows for each student.

Comment: Its still the same , only if there is more than one matching student id in course table the result displays as expected.

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to fix the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: If i do LIMIT 0,1 or LIMT 1 the preference is ignored , the query fetches the latest  course for each student .

Comment: You also need to change the order from `DESC` to `ASC`, because you want the field with the lowest number.